# PHP passing JSON data using Ajax for inArray() comparison

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to check an user input in a html form to a list of allowable values in a database using Ajax and then I want to display the corresponding message. This is the code I'm using:

js

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'datafile.php',
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(result) {
          $("#postal_code").change(function(){
            var postal_code = $("#postal_code").val().slice(0,-2);
            if ($.inArray(postal_code,result) !== -1){
             console.log('success');
            } else {
              console.log('failure');
            }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

datafile.php

```
<?php
require_once("./db_con.php");

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT postal_code FROM table");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($query);
echo json_encode($rows);
mysqli_free_result($query);
mysqli_close($con);
exit();
?>
```

The problem I'm having is the input value never matches any of the values in the `result` variable even through I know that they are in the database. I think the issue is related to the fact that the `result` variable contains arrays in side another array, e.g. `[["value1"],["value2"],["value3"]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really speak to the JavaScript portion, but since you are only selecting one column you can extract it into a single dimension.  `mysqli_fetch_all` fetches a numerically indexed array by default:

```
$rows = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($query), 0);
```

Or fetch and extract by column name:

```
$rows = array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'postal_code');
```

Comment: Thanks using the `array_column()` on the server side solved the problem!